# Valid Edit accepted by OP, but rejected by Reviewers

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I had made [one Edit Suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1815897) to this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485929/best-approximation-by-coprime-numbers), but it was rejected.
I was wondering whether I was mistaken and the Edit is wrong. Hence, I then made the same Edit Suggestion via Comment and OP incorporated the Edit !

It seems my Edit Suggestion was indeed valid. But why then was it rejected ?

UPDATE :
It is not wording or formatting issue which is mostly Opinion or subjective.

It was a factually "incorrect" Part in the Post, which was "corrected" by my Edit.

Where it was "CP is the set of coprime integers", I suggested "CP is the set of **PAIRS** of coprime integers", because there is no concept of "set of coprime integers".

Comment: The original poster making an edit based on your comment does not mean your comment was correct; only that they agreed with it.  Likewise, a reviewer rejecting your edit doesn't mean it was 'wrong' (which could be any of wrong, ineffective, unhelpful or something else); only that they felt your edit wasn't good enough.  Unless a reviewer of your proposed edit cares to answer, you (and we) will never know why it was rejected.

Comment: I will include a [link to the suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1815897). It is worth mentioning that the owner of the post can override the decision made by other reviewers - as you can read in the FAQ post: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

Comment: One factor could have been the **BOLDALLCAPS**. But I guess it should have been Improved

Comment: I used BOLDALLCAPS PAIRS, to Emphasize the Change, which might otherwise look like no change or minor change; But you are right, that could be the Issue! @CalvinKhor

Comment: @Prem as you can see from the suggested edit link, your changes are highlighted. So it shouldn't be necessary to bold

Comment: Note that when a suggested edit is rejected by Reviewers, the OP is *notified* of the rejection and given an opportunity to override the rejection vote and accept the edit (or improve it).

Comment: As one of those who rejected the edit, I'll tell you my reason. The set CP is defined later in the very same sentence: the addition of another word doesn't help explain to the reader what's going on. Edits, IMO, have to add more than this.